# How to substitute an aggregate expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For example, I have symbollically

```
1/n*Sum[ee[k] + 1, {k, j, n}]^2
```

And I want to substitute `Sum[ee[k], {k, j+1, n}]` to be `x`. How can I do this? May thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the recurrence relation for the sum. For example:

```
f[j] := f[j + 1] + (ee[j] + 1);

1/N f[j]^2 /. f[j + 1] -> x
```

Out

```
(1 + x + ee[j])^2/N
```

**Edit**

Based on several questions you posted, I think you are somehow misinterpreting what the Replace[] command does. It is not "algebraic" based, but "pattern" based. It doesn't understand nor use more algebraic transformations than those already defined (by you or by Mma itself).

For example:

```
x/. (x-1)->y
```

will not match anything.   But

```
(x-1) /. x->y-1
```

Will give you (y-2) because **the pattern** x is matched.

Moreover:

```
x = 3;
(x - 1) /. x -> y - 1
```

will give you **2** because x is evaluated before the possible match, and the x in the pattern is also evaluated (just paste, execute and look at the symbol color).

Answer (score 1):

`1/N*Sum[ee[k] + 1, {k, j, N}]^2 /. Sum[ee[k] + 1, {k, j, N}] -> x`

Doesn't that work, or do I misunderstand? By the way, you shouldn't use N as a variable. It's a Mathematica function.

Comment: did you notice the `j+1` in the substitution?